# How to convert two vectors into dataframe (wide format)

Tags: r

I want to convert two vectors into a wide format dataframe. The fist vector represent the column names and the second vector the values.
Here is my reproduceable example:

```
vector1<-c("Reply","Reshare","Like","Share","Search")
vector2<-c(2,1,0,4,3)
```

Now I want to convert these two vector into a wide format dataframe:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 5
   Reply Reshare  Like Share Search
   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1     2       1     0     4      3
```

I have found some examples for the long format, but none simple solution for the wide format. Can anyone help me?

Comment: ´rbind(vector1, vector2)´

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a named list (e.g. using `setNames`), followed by `as.data.frame`:

```
df <- as.data.frame(setNames(as.list(vector2), vector1))
```

Note that it needs to be a *list:* when converting a named *vector* into a `data.frame`, R puts values into separate rows instead of columns.

Answer (score 2):

```r
vector1<-c("Reply","Reshare","Like","Share","Search")
vector2<-c(2,1,0,4,3)

df <- data.frame(vector1, vector2)
df |> tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = vector1, values_from = vector2)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 5
#>   Reply Reshare  Like Share Search
#>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1     2       1     0     4      3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Please Note that the native pipe operator `|>` is only available for R with versions >=4.1

Answer (score 2):

Yet another solution, based on `dplyr::bind_rows`:

```r
library(dplyr)

vector1<-c("Reply","Reshare","Like","Share","Search")
vector2<-c(2,1,0,4,3)

names(vector2) <- vector1
bind_rows(vector2)

#> # A tibble: 1 × 5
#>   Reply Reshare  Like Share Search
#>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1     2       1     0     4      3
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `map_dfc` and `set_names`

```
library(purrr)

set_names(map_dfc(vector2, ~.x), vector1)

# A tibble: 1 × 5
  Reply Reshare  Like Share Search
  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1     2       1     0     4      3
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
library(dplyr)

data.frame(rbind(vector1, vector2)) %>%
  `colnames<-`(.[1, ]) %>%
  .[-1, ] %>% 
  `rownames<-`(NULL)

  Reply Reshare Like Share Search
1     2       1    0     4      3
```